# MYSQL Select to file

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to save the output from a "Select * FROM table1" in console to a file in PHP.

What would be the most efficient way to do this in php?

Edit:
I'd like the output to be like the type in the console ie.

```
+--------+--------+
| thing1 | thing2 |
+--------+--------+
| item1a | item2a |
| item1b | item2b |
+--------+--------+
```

Also, I was thinking that the php code should be "exec(mysql command which I'm looking for)". It's my understanding that mysql_fetch_array is slow, and I'm looking for a simple output...so it should be possible to somehow do this from the console. (Thanks for the responses thus far!)

Comment: May I ask why you need it formatted like the console? That makes it harder to import. What are you going to be using the output for?

Comment: This isn't really for importing...this is for printing/viewing. This output will be stored in a text file which can be viewed by virtually any browser/low bandwidth in case my fancier html table sorter doesn't work on the individual's browser, or they have a bad/poor bandwidth connection. Also, very primitive but sufficient printout.

Comment: Something to consider is that a CSV file is a format read by most programs.  What it lacks in immediate readability, can be loaded into Excel or other spreadsheet software which would provide the ability to filter further, hide columns from visibility, sorting, and graphing.

Comment: I'm aware of the versatility that CSV provides...though I'd still like to know how to print the mysql console output to a file....for something as popular as mysql there should be a way (I hope).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [MySQL's INTO OUTFILE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) - this would produce a comma separated value (CSV) text file:

```
SELECT *
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Permissions to write files to the location specified need to be in place.

Comment: Plus the file can't exist already. MySQL will not overwrite an existing file as a security precaution.

Comment: Just to emphasize that writing to /tmp/ is the least problematic approach. I tried writing to a different location and it failed despite giving the mysql user ownership.

Answer (score 3):

In what format? If you want them tab separated, you can use something like this:

```
$r   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
$str = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $str .= implode("\t", $row)."\n";
}

file_put_contents('table1.txt', $str);
```

Or, in CSV:

```
$r  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");    
$fp = fopen('table1.csv', 'w');

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Or, as others noted, use MySQL's own OUTFILE which I was unaware of. :)