# Pretty-print Node.js MySQL SELECT query response to console/variable

Tags: mysql, node.js, command-line-interface, pretty-print

How do I prettyprint a MySQL SELECT query in node.js to the console or to a variable(that I can in turn print to the console)? Any suggested modules/techniques for prettyprinting mysql output in node.js?

I'm looking for output similar what the mysql command line provides for select queries:

`SELECT thing1, thing2 FROM Things`

```
+--------+--------+
| thing1 | thing2 |
+--------+--------+
| item1a | item2a |
| item1b | item2b |
+--------+--------+
```

A while ago I had asked a similar question for [pretty printing mysql select in php to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061359/mysql-select-to-file).

Comment: this might be useful: https://github.com/Automattic/cli-table

Answer (score 1):

you can use morgan for purrty logs

to install it

npm  install morgan

note : use inside express